# Assembly Referencing in C# in Hierarchical order

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I have an class library A containing class1A, class2A, class3A. Then I have another class library B containing Class1B which inherit from class1A of assembly A.

I am going to give assembly B to a third party but without assembly A. Now the problem is the third party cannot use the objects of classes1A in class1B until the project references the assembly A.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this. The reason is that I don't want the third party to access classes of assembly A directly.

Comment: its like google hasnt been invented for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve your desired behaviour without refactoring your "library A".

But if refactoring is possible - you can change all `public` classes in library A to be `internal`, and then appying [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to these classes you can give "library B" permission to use them.

Of course, in this case you still need to give "library A" to your customer and he will not be able to use its classes directly *in usual way*. But note - it is still possible to access non-public methods and classes of any assembly using [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) and you can't prevent this access.